# Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: enterprise-search, fast-for-sharepoint

In Sharepoint 2010 crawl log, I am getting below error and no success record in crawling -

"This item could not be crawled because the repository did not respond within the specified timeout period. Try to crawl the repository at a later time, or increase the timeout value on the Proxy and Timeout page in search administration. You might also want to crawl this repository during off-peak usage times.

SharePoint site: WebExceptionStatus TrustFailure The underlying connection was closed Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Thanks

Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options: Either you import the certificate to the Certificate store of the crawler (and the SharePoint Cert Store [Central Admin > Security > Manage Trust and upload the root certifcate of the repository]) or you go to Central Admin - Farm Search Administration ( url-of-central-admin/searchfarmdashboard.aspx) and click on "Ignore SSL Warnings" > Yes.

Hope it helps!
Max